# Fetch images from database in balde view in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-blade

I save images in my database(the name of the image) and the images are saved in my public/images directory(it works). I have one too many relationships and I put a `dd()` to see if I get the data correctly from the database and yes, It is correct. Now I want to have in my view those images but I don't know how to write the correct path for this. I try something like this :

```
@foreach($result as $res)

@foreach($res->images as $file)//in images i have the pics
<tr>
 <td><img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $file->file_name)}}" /></td>

</tr>
@endforeach
@endforeach``
```

But `$file->file_name` is not treated as a variable in Visual studio code. How can I obtain the correct path to display my pics correctly? thank you

Comment: it shows a little green pictogram

Comment: I don't see my pictures in blade view, that's the error..I just see that pictogram instead a picture

Comment: check what url is generated and posted in question

Comment: the dd() result is : "{{ asset('public/images/' . car.png)}}"

Comment: In broswer `<img src=""` in this tag what url ? is generating ?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/images/car.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `public` from  `asset()` function, this helper point to `public` dir

```php
<td><img src="{{ asset('images/' . $file->file_name)}}" /></td>
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset